# Using PDF.js web worker cross domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf.js

First time using `pdf.js` and I'm not much good at javascript. I'm trying to view a pdf file cross domain using `pdf.js`. I found one solution to face with cross domain : http://colonelpanic.net/2014/08/using-pdf-js-web-worker-cross-domain-cors/
 and a sample example from https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld

Here what I try : http://jsfiddle.net/4cn4hvq5/ , it  shows only a canvas not pdf.

I want something like http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html but just to change from local pdf to other domain's pdf.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Run the script. What does the JavaScript console say? Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct?

Comment: @Quentin As I mentioned, I am just a javascript newbie, so please excuse my ignorance.